# How do I insert text at the focus into a markitup editor with javascript?

Tags: javascript, markdown, markitup

I've implemented [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) to handle users entering markdown text. I want to replace the default image insert command with a nice jquery routine that lets the user browse for an image. I'm able to edit the `set.js` file to call my javascript routine that brings up the file browser:

```
{name: 'Picture', key: 'P', call: 'insertImage'},
```

My `insertImage` function looks like this:

```
function insertImage()
{
    // launch Image Browser
}
```

When the user selects an image in the image browser, another javascript function is called:

```
function addImage(imageurl,alttext)
{
    var imagetext = "!["+alttext+"]("+imageurl+")";
    // how do I insert imageurl into markitup??
}
```

I need help implementing `addImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
function addImage(imageurl,alttext)
{
    var imagetext = "!["+alttext+"]("+imageurl+")";
    $.markItUp({ replaceWith: imagetext });
}
```